unable to restart ser2net on docker container after editing ser2net.yml ad restarting docker
Edited /etc/ser2net.yml file in docker container.

Added following entry in the ser2net file:
connection: &con40000
    accepter: tcp,40000
    enable: on
    options:
      banner: *banner
      kickolduser: true
      telnet-brk-on-sync: true
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/ttyUSB0,
              115200n81,local nobreak


Restarted docker container:
docker stop my_container
docker start my_container


Entered back into container
docker exec -it my_container bash

But failed to restart ser2net:
$ systemctl restart ser2net
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down



Here is the complete ser2net.yml file
%YAML 1.1
---
# This is a ser2net configuration file, tailored to be rather
# simple.
#
# Find detailed documentation in ser2net.yaml(5)
# A fully featured configuration file is in
# /usr/share/doc/ser2net/examples/ser2net.yaml.gz
#
# If you find your configuration more useful than this very simple
# one, please submit it as a bugreport

define: &banner \r\nser2net port \p device \d [\B] (Debian GNU/Linux)\r\n\r\n

connection: &con0096
    accepter: tcp,2000
    enable: on
    options:
      banner: *banner
      kickolduser: true
      telnet-brk-on-sync: true
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/ttyS0,
              9600n81,local

connection: &con1096
    accepter: tcp,2001
    enable: on
    options:
      banner: *banner
      kickolduser: true
      telnet-brk-on-sync: true
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/ttyS1,
              9600n81,local

connection: &con0192
    accepter: tcp,3000
    enable: on
    options:
      banner: *banner
      kickolduser: true
      telnet-brk-on-sync: true
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/ttyS0,
              19200n81,local

connection: &con1192
    accepter: tcp,3001
    enable: on
    options:
      banner: *banner
      kickolduser: true
      telnet-brk-on-sync: true
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/ttyS1,
              19200n81,local

connection: &con40000
    accepter: tcp,40000
    enable: on
    options:
      banner: *banner
      kickolduser: true
      telnet-brk-on-sync: true
    connector: serialdev,
              /dev/ttyUSB0,
              115200n81,local nobreak


given that i don't know specifically this container, are you sure it implements systemd?
have you tried things like "service ser2net restart"?

It is highly unlikely that your container is running systemd (or any other process manager, for that matter). Please update this question to include your Dockerfile, or if you're not building the image yourself then a link to the upstream image.

Ok thanks to @realpclaudio for pointing out - it did not implement systemd.
The following two solutions worked:
$ docker exec -it hacpy_container pkill ser2net
$ docker exec -it hacpy_container ser2net -c /path/to/ser2net.yml
Unable to start mdns: Out of memory #<- this still restarted ser2net

and
$ service ser2net restart 
Unable to start mdns: Out of memory #<- this still restarted ser2net

Initially, I was a bit confused on the unable to start mdns: Out of memory but it did not cause any issues with ser2net port mapping.
